# How to display a node in overlay popup effect?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialogs

I have a content type 'students' with fields name, description and a photo. I have created a view(Block) to display only the images of the students. When the teacher/user clicks the photo of the student, It must show up the name, description and the photo of the student in a overlay/lightbox effect.

I have tried using Lightbox2 and colorbox node module to achieve as per my needs, But needed up in failure. Any help is widely appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the error or problem you are getting while doing it with lightbox2 ?

Comment: I could just display the image in the lightbox, It does  not shows the full node. I tried both Lightframe and lightshow rel.

Comment: You could display any link in popup using lighnbox. Just add rel="lightbox" in your anchor type where you are giving the link of the node and the node will pop-up. :-)

Comment: I added lightbox to the rel (Just made it with the firebug) and the page is redirected to the full node page:(

Comment: NO, Do not do it with firebug. As lightbox2 js is used to check all the link which has rel='lightbox' on the page ready state. so your firebug edit will never work. Do it in static block in drupal and then test. I am sure it will work.

Comment: I created a template file for the view's field and added rel=lightbox to the a tag in the template file. I could see the lightbox effect while clicking the image but It just shows a broken image in the overlay effect. Am I missing something else???

Comment: Thanks a lot j2r:):) What I needed was node/nid/lightbox in the href and lightframe in the rel. If u had not suggested to go ahead with lightbox, I think I would taken another day or so to solve this. Thanks once again:):)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. Based on j2r's comments and http://drupal.org/node/1378438 question from this node I was able to solve my issue.

Create href as node/nid/lightbox and rel as lightframe. This will result in displaying the whole page in the lightbox. To avoid this U need to create a page--contenttype.tpl.php (In my case) http://www.digett.com/blog/01/11/2012/overriding-page-templates-content-type-drupal-7 and then remove the header, footer and other unwanted regions in the page.

Once this is done I am sure u will get as what I got.

Comment: I am unable to do that now, I need to wait for another 2 days to accept:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module. You need module development skills to achieve above functionality. You need to create a new ctools menu path, and pass the nid to that menu callback to display related details.

Check it out the ctools_ajax_sample module inside ctools module for implementation of overlay popup.