# Open node as popup with Lightbox 2

Tags: 7, javascript

I recently upgraded my site to Drupal 7 and felt a need for opening some specific node as popup using Lightbox 2.

I have been through the documentation, and I found out that in Drupal 7 this feature can be implemented by adding a new template file in theme's directory named page--node--[nid].tpl.php.

The problem is that, when I implemented it this way, I wasn't able to view the node content properly as in the template I removed the header, sidebars etc.

So when I try to access the node via www.example.com/node/[nid] only content would appear without showing any headers or sidebars.

So has anyone implemented this feature using Lightbox 2 in Drupal 7?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as written, it is a polling question.

Answer (score 1):

In your tpl.php file only have the following

```
<?php print render($content); ?>
```

If you want to style it you can wrap divs around.

Then add a `rel="lightframe"` attribute in your link that will trigger lightbox.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/node/[nid]" rel="lightframe">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this goal you can use [Colorbox](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox) module + [Colorbox Node](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) module.

You also should take a look at the following question:

[How to display a node in overlay popup effect?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45925/how-to-display-a-node-in-overlay-popup-effect)